# TypeError: (0 , _services_cryptoApi_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.useGetCryptoQuery) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

```
const createRequest = (url) => ({ url, headers: cryptoApiHeaders });
export const cryptoApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "cryptoApi",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getCrypto: builder.query({
      query: () => createRequest("/coins"),
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetCryptoQuery } = cryptoApi;
```

#So i am importing the endpoint useGetCryptoQuery , in the code block below

```
import { useGetCryptoQuery } from "../services/cryptoApi.js";
//const { Title } = Typography;
const Homepage = () => {
  const { data, isFetching } = useGetCryptoQuery();
  if (isFetching) return <div>Loading</div>;

  console.log(data);
```

**However  i am getting this error ,,,.useGetCryptoQuery) is not a function **

I am expecting my code to work coz i have exported as expected.